# Locking only a subset of threats in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I am quite new to working with threads.

I am writing an application in python which needs to check whether an attribute value from a bunch of json objects is in the database; if not, insert them and send a message to another application. I would like to process this one object per thread.

If multiple objects have the same attribute value that is missing in the database, I need to make sure multiple threads won't try to add it at the same time, as this will confuse the other application. So, something like this would be in order:

```
lock.acquire()
    if object.attribute not in database:
        insert value into database
        send message
    else:
        <process it>
lock.release()
```

However, the lock should affect only the threads whose assigned objects have the same attribute value, as otherwise the operation is safe.

What would be a good way to go about this?

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: btw, does `<process it>` part need to be done in locked section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to maintain a list of "currently locked" attribute values and use that in conjunction with a condition-variable lock. Something like this:

```
cvlock.acquire()
while attribute_val in attribute_val_list:
  cvlock.wait()
attribute_val_list.append(attribute_val)
cvlock.release()

# Do your thing.

cvlock.acquire()
attribute_val_list.remove(attribute_val)
cvlock.notifyAll()
cvlock.release()
```

Whenever a thread is going to add its object to the database, it adds the attribute value to `attribute_val_list`, which is protected by the `cvlock` from multiple threads trying to modify it at once. While this thread is working, any other threads that have the same attribute value will be redirected to `cvlock.wait()`, until the first thread is done working and removes `attribute_val` from `attribute_val_list`. Any threads that have different attribute values will be able to proceed as normal.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#condition-objects

Comment: In this case it should be `cvlock.notifyAll()` in the second block of code, as otherwise first block may get starved if waken up by release of other than observed `attribute_val`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have proper unique constraints in your database, you won't need to use any locking. Simply send your message only if insert succeeds. No thread level locking needed. Even if there's no constraints, you can't add them and repeated inserts for the same values are possible, you may use database transactions with proper isolation level.

Comment: This is true, but the problematic part is reporting to the other application over which I don't have control, and which will create a new record for every message I send it - and I need to avoid this.

Comment: But like I've written above, if your insert fails, you should skip notifying other application, so it won't repeated messages.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I missed that part due to being easily exciteable :) I was considering it, but the processing part also depends on the value being in the database. So maybe I could get rid of the if statement, try to insert it every time, and process it only if if fails because the value is already present?